# NestJS returning the result of an HTTP request

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, axios, nestjs

In my NestJS application I want to return the result of an http call.

Following the example of the [NestJS HTTP module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module), what I'm doing is simply:

```
import { Controller, HttpService, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosResponse } from '@nestjs/common/http/interfaces/axios.interfaces';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';

@Controller('authenticate')
export class AuthController {

  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  @Post()
  authenticate(): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.post(...);
  }
}
```

However from the client I'm getting 500 and the server console is saying:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at stringify (/Users/francesco.borzi/sources/business-controller-rewrite/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1119:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/Users/francesco.borzi/sources/business-controller-rewrite/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
>       at ExpressAdapter.reply (/Users/francesco.borzi/sources/business-controller-rewrite/node_modules/@nestjs/core/adapters/express-adapter.js:41:52)
>       at RouterResponseController.apply (/Users/francesco.borzi/sources/business-controller-rewrite/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-response-controller.js:11:36)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)

Comment: Maybe httpService return some non-valid JSON, and NestJS (Express) throw the error because cannot convert. Try call something simple with httpService, maybe simple test GET.

Comment: from what is my understanding, NestJS should automatically convert to json.. am I right?

Comment: Yes, it should convert automatically by default.

Comment: As I'm experiencing the same exact thing, I tried testing with another source that I'm 100% positive is returning valid json and it's still giving the same error. Same result when using GET.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This issue comes from the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library. In order to fix that, you have to pull out the `data` property:

```
return this.httpService.post(...)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.data),
  );
```

Comment: So I had to learn this on my on. But now I want to push the original HTTP Status code in the case of an error. Any tips?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this isn't fixed as of today

Answer (score 11):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that we are trying to return a Response object directly, and that is circular by nature. I'm not sure of the correct way to implement this, but I was able to get around it by using axios directly, unwrapping the promise and returning just the data.

```
@Post('login')
  async authenticateUser(@Body() LoginDto) {
    const params = JSON.stringify(LoginDto);

    return await axios.post('https://api.example.com/authenticate_user',
      params,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }).then((res) => {
          return res.data;
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

I realized I could just do the same thing to the Observable being returned from the `httpService` using the new rxjs pipe method, so that's probably the better way to do it.

```
@Post('login')
async authenticateUser(@Body() LoginDto) {
    const params = JSON.stringify(LoginDto);

    return this.httpService.post('https://api.example.com/authenticate_user',
      params,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }).pipe(map((res) => {
    return res.data;
  }));
}
```

Comment: @andyrune. Sorry , I just wanted to point out that async await doesn't work with Observables. It works only with promises. I believe you have to convert your observable to a promise and then use async/await.

Comment: @andyrune, why controller here, make api call and hit another api instead of directly return data from database?

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa In my case the authentication api is on a different server.

Comment: This works, but is really ugly imo. Why is making http request implemented in such a weird way?

Comment: I am not getting any response, when I tried to console.log the response

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who are familiar with Axios and want to stick to that, here's the solution I can suggest:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
 constructor(private readonly http: HttpService){}

 fetch(url, params) {
  return this.http.axiosRef.get(url, params)
  }

}
```

Comment: HttpService class is imported from @nestjs/axios

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for HTTP Data, HTTP Status code and wanted to convert an observable to a promise using firstValueFrom ('rxjs')

```
const responseData = await firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.post(url, data, config).pipe(map((response) => [response.data, response.status])),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response = await this.httpService.post(...);
return response.data
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.